# Eclipse - supporting outline view with require.js define(...)

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angularjs, eclipse-plugin, requirejs

I have a large code writing within [define(...)](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define)  as the following format -

```
define(['angular'], function(angular) {
        function foo () {
            console.log("Hi") ; 
        }
        function foo2 () {
            console.log("Hi") ; 
        }
        function foo3 () {
            console.log("Hi") ; 
        }
} )
```

The Eclipse is missing all the [outline view](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcoutline.htm) output for this format , mean - showing nothing  .

How to make it supporting this format , mean - direct me to all function and variables declaration  ?

Here my current outline view is attached -

[image]

Comment: Please detail what you wish to expect at https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/issues/289

Answer (score 8):

JSDT Plugins which is the default Eclipse plugins for JavaScript doesn't support RequireJS. I suggest you that you try tern.java (I'm the author of tern.java) which gives a [support for RequireJS](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-RequireJS-support). You will benefit with RequireJS completion, hyperlink, hover, validation.

I suggets you that you [install AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) 0.8.0 (not released) which is based on tern.java (as it seems you are using angular). You will have again Outline problem (tern.java doesn't fix that), but don't hesitate to [create issues](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/issues) with your idea to improve tern.java.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try out the Aptana Studio plugin. Their plugin offers a lot of nice front-end web development tooling.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java).

I suggest you that you [install 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) which provides a [Tern Explorer view](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Outline-support). Here a screenshot with your sample:

[image: Tern Explorer]

Answer (score 1):

Try to put JsDoc "@memberOf" before the inner function. 

See sample below. You may see "doValidation" and "put" function at outline view under "MyNameSpace" class.

For more information about JsDoc, check this out http://kajabity.com/2012/02/how-i-introduced-jsdoc-into-a-javascript-project-and-found-my-eclipse-outline/ .

[Snapshot from SuiteScript 2.0 RestLet. SuiteScript2.0 is integrated with RequireJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdzan.png)

Actual sample here:

```
"use strict"; //Defines that JavaScript code should be executed in "strict mode
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Restlet
 */
define(
    [
            'N/record', 'N/error'
    ],

/**
 * @param {record} record 
 */
function(record, error)
{
    /**
     * @memberOf myNameSpace
     */
    function doValidation(args, argNames, methodName)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            if (!args[i] && args[i] !== 0)
            {
                throw error.create(
                    {
                        name : 'MISSING_REQ_ARG',
                        message : 'Missing a required argument: [' + argNames[i] + '] for method: ' + methodName
                    });
            }
        }
    }
    // Upsert a NetSuite record from request param
    /**
     * @memberOf myNameSpace
     */
    function put(context)
    {
        doValidation(
            [
                    context.recordtype, context.id
            ],
            [
                    'recordtype', 'id'
            ], 'PUT');
        var rec = record.load(
            {
                type : context.recordtype,
                id : context.id
            });
        for ( var fldName in context)
            if (context.hasOwnProperty(fldName))
            {
                if (fldName !== 'recordtype' && fldName !== 'id')
                {
                    rec.setValue(fldName, context[fldName]);
                }
            }
        rec.save();
        return JSON.stringify(rec);
    }
    return (
        {
            post : post
        });
});
```